# Pulseaudio - Sound starts to get distorted/crackling after supsend

Tags: 14.04, pulseaudio

First off, I know there are lots of threads but none helped me yet.

Basically my audio output works great, but for some reason it starts to get distorted. I think it is related to the suspend.

After I wake my PC from suspension the sound starts to be crackling/distorted.

The most common advice I found is to append `tsched=0` to the line `load-module module-udev-detect` in the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`. However, this did not changed anything.

The only "solution" I found is to execute the following command:

> killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse*

This fixes my issue. However, the issue will occur probably after the next suspend.
Do you maybe have any solution?

Comment: I've got the same issue on 20.04 :(